# Scheme Homework Assignment

Tags: scheme, racket

In a course I am taking we recently had to learn the programming language Scheme. I get all of the basics, which is pretty much all that we have gone though. I'm just having trouble learning to think in the different way that Scheme consists of.

I was given an assignment and really do not even know how to start. I have sat here for a few hours trying to figure out how to even get started, but I'm kind of stumped. For the record, I'm not asking for the code to solve this problem, but more of some thoughts to get me on the right track.

Anyway, here is the gist of the assignment...

We are given a list of ten numbers that represent a voter's votes. The numbers are -1, 0 or 1. Then we are given a list of lists of Candidates, with a name and then ten numbers corresponding to that candidate's votes. These numbers are also -1 0 and 1.

So for example.

```
'(0 0 0 -1 -1 1 0 1 0 -1)
'(Adams 0 1 -1 0 1 1 0 -1 -1 0 0)
```

We are asked to implement a function called best_candidates that will take in a list of numbers (Voter) and a list of lists of Candidates. Then we have to compare the votes of the voter against the list of each candidate and return a list of names with the most common votes.

So far, I've come up with a few things. I'm just confused on how I will check the values and retain the name of the voter? I guess I'm still stuck in thinking C/Java and it's making this very tough.

Any suggestions to help get me started?

Comment: i'm not a scheme expert, but this might be helpful: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this a standard search problem where you're looking for items that have *minimal* difference (i.e. "the most common").

That is, given a list of items **x_0**, **x_1**, ..., **x_n**,  I think you want to write a function that computes a corresponding set of disagreement numbers **d_0**, **d_1**, ..., **d_n**.

Once you can compute these **d_i** disagreement numbers, find out which one (or ones!) are smallest: these correspond to maximal agreement.

If you can do that, then the corresponding **x_i**'s are the list items you want to collect.

Nothing about the description above is dependent on programming language.  If you're more comfortable with another language, code it up in that language first!  You should gain enough confidence and understanding of the problem to make the extra work worthwhile.  At the very least, you'll have another implementation that you can use to test against your Scheme implementation to make sure you get *agreement*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have coded this problem in Java already and it was fairly simple for me. 

Your way with finding the lists with the smallest disagreement numbers is interesting and not a way I was trying. 

The biggest problem that I'm having is once I figure out which lists are the ones that I need, how would I go about putting the names of that candidate into a new list and returning that?

Comment: In your Java solution, I'm guessing you have a loop. Can you describe what you do in that loop? I'm guessing one of those things is to count the number of votes in common with the voter. The first thing I would do would be to develop the function that takes a voter and a candidate and return the number of votes they have in common (or, as Danny says, the number of votes that are different).